# Running app from android studio not working

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

when I run my app from android studio to my phone (Sony Z3), it doesn't seem to install correctly.  when running to an emulator it works fine, but on the device my anti virus checks it but is not there. I can see it under the app management settings but it wont run.  I've been developing for a few months and this is the first time I've seen anything like this so I'm not even sure what code or logs to show you all!!.

I have feeling its the ADB and have tried various things to solve this including reinstalling Android studio and the SDK with no luck.  any advice guys as this is driving me mad.  I've put some of the logs received below.

```
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device BH90T0U51L: device offline
PropertyFetcher: AdbCommandRejectedException getting properties for device BH90T0U51L: device offline
DeviceMonitor: ExecutionException getting info for device BH90T0U51L
```

Comment: Double check if developer options is activated and USB debugging is ON.

Comment: Update your sdk build tools through the sdk manager. Disable/uninstall your anti-virus. Disable/uninstall any third party tethering apps (some of those use adb under the covers). Uninstall/delete the application from your phone. Restart your phone. Restart your computer. Make sure you're using the same usb cable that originally came with your phone. Not all usb cables are the same. When testing, use the adb commands directly from the command line (there are extra flags you can use to give you more info). Also, you didn't say what computer you are using. Are you using Windows, a Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Xperia Connectivity -> Usb Connectivity -> Usb connection mode -> Check MTP mode.

Click Revoke USB debugging authorization in Developer option and try it again.

And try sudo adb devices.